# Error in Parsing Long LOG files?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, logparser

I have a LOG Parser program written in java that write all required time stamps on CVS file. When I run it I am getting error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at LogParser.getTimeStampForABlock(LogParser.java:98)
>       at LogParser.main(LogParser.java:45)

Comment: Please post code that will fully compile

Answer (score 1):

Line 98, `result` can be null, so you need to check for null before this line:

`return result.substring(result.indexOf("[")+1, result.indexOf("]"));`

Comment: i tried many but getting same error... any suggestion where and what changes are required in code?

Comment: Can you post a reasonably short CSV which produces the NullPointerException?

Comment: there are 2 csvs... one(log csv hold captured Uids) used for searching required UIDs time stamp from Logfile.... i am sending you both...

Comment: how to post cvs here?

Comment: Edit your initial question with to contents.

Comment: added log.csv content to question

Comment: With no sample CEPLogger.log (I used an empty file), I am at the very least compelled to replace this line: `return result.substring(result.indexOf("[")+1, result.indexOf("]"));` by: `return (result != null) ? result.substring(result.indexOf("[") + 1, result.indexOf("]")) : null;`

Comment: fbb7a5d6-efaa-4244-972d-8a374d4dc4c1,  2016-07-25 09:32:43.334 , null, null, null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at LogParser.main(LogParser.java:50)

Comment: msg me your email id.  i will send you .log file

Comment: Can any other expert look into this?